# find only one row from table in foreign with another tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 tables gallery(Gallery_ID,Name) and Gallery_Image(ID,Gallery_ID,Image). My question is i want to select only one image of each gallery

i have tried this query

```
SELECT distinct  top 1  Gallery.Gallery_ID, Gallery.Gallery_Name,Gallery.Gallery_Name  as Gallery_Image
FROM         Gallery 
    union
select distinct Gallery_Image.Gallery_ID,Gallery_Image.Gallery_Images as Gallery_Name,Gallery_Image.Gallery_Images
from Gallery_Image inner join Gallery on Gallery.Gallery_ID=Gallery_Image.Gallery_ID
where Gallery_Image.Gallery_ID in(select Gallery_ID from Gallery)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:  "i want to select only one image of each gallery."  This makes sense.  I have no idea how your query relates to this question.

You don't specify which database you are using.  A good approach is to use `row_number()` to assign a sequential order to the images within a gallery.  The key is to do a random sort.  The last piece depends on the database.  Here is the SQL Server syntax:

```
select gi.*
from (select gi.*, row_number() over (partition by Gallery_Id order by newid()) as seqnum
      from Gallery_Image gi
     ) gi
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

To get information from the `Gallery` table, join it in:

```
select gi.*
from (select gi.*, row_number() over (partition by Gallery_Id order by newid()) as seqnum
      from Gallery_Image gi
     ) gi join
     Gallery g
     on gi.Gallery_Id = g.Gallery_Id and
        seqnum = 1;
```

I also moved the logic to take the "first" image to the `on` clause from the `where` clause.

Comment: @SunnySandeep . . . If I interpreted the question correctly, then the solution works for that database.

Comment: i want to select gallery name also.so please help me.i am using sql server 2008